# \r\n translated to \r\r\n in Haskell

Tags: haskell, newline

I'm on Windows 7 64-bit.

My program needs to retrieve some text (Utf8 encoded) from an external source, do some things with it, then save it to disk. The original text is using the "\r\n" sequence to represent newlines (I am happy to keep it that way).

**The issue** : When using Data.Text.writeFile each "\r\n" sequence seems to be translated as "\r\r\n", that is every '\n' is translated to "\r\n", *even when it is already preceded by '\r' in the original text*. I understand that, when writing to a file on Windows OS, '\n' should be translated to a "\r\n", when not already preceded by '\r' , but the translation of "\r\n" to "\r\r\n" does not seem right.

Using ByteString.writeLine applied to the encodeUtf8 version of the text works well though (no extra "\r" inserted inside a "\r\n" sequence)

A simple example :

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import qualified Data.ByteString as B
import qualified Data.Text as T
import qualified Data.Text.IO as T (writeFile)
import qualified Data.Text.Encoding as T (encodeUtf8)

str = "Line 1 is here\r\nLine 2 is here\r\nLine 3 is here" :: T.Text

main = do
    B.writeFile "byt.bin" $ T.encodeUtf8 str
    T.writeFile "txt.bin" str
```

Looking at each file produced by this code with an hex editor, one can see the extra x0D added in front of each x0A in the file produced via the T.writeFile line.

B.writeFile : 
[image]

T.writeFile :
[image]

**My question** : What did I do wrong? Is there a way to use T.writeFile on Windows, and not get "\r\n" translated to "\r\r\n"?

Comment: Why don't you _load_ the file to Unix-style `"\n"`-only? That would certainly make things easier within your program, and the output would also come out right with `"\r\n"`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout : I did not tell the whole story, but the original text is located in a file in base64 format. I first need to read the BytesStrings from the file, decode them (using Data.ByteString.Base64), then turn them into Text (and I can start to manipulate it). At that stage I could replace all "\r\n" to "\n". Is that what you suggest?

Comment: I would indeed suggest so. It might well lead to all kinds of other trouble if you have Windows-style line endings in the strings in your program.

Comment: What leftaroundabout says is of course right, \r\n is pretty non-standard and you should get rid of it in your internal representation. I also think letting the OS handle your string coding for output is generally a bad idea, it might lead to other problems too (e.g. strings being encoded as some other coding than UTF-8, BOM vs. no BOM etc.) But that's just a personal opinion

Answer (score 10):

Your answer is in [the docs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.1.1/docs/Data-Text-IO.html):

> Beginning with GHC 6.12, text I/O is performed using the system or handle's current locale and line ending conventions.

Seeing as you do not open the handle yourself, it seems very likely that the library opens the file in text mode, leading to the translation of endline characters by the operating system. What you could do instead is open the file in binary mode using [`openBinaryFile`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/System-IO.html#v:openBinaryFile) and then use [`Data.Text.hPutStr`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.1.1/docs/Data-Text-IO.html#v:hPutStr) to prevent this.

However, the OS handling your encoding might also not be what you want. Depending on your scenario, encoding/decoding the string explicitly like you do using `ByteString`s might be the better idea.

Comment: Thanks. I confirm that the solution openBinaryFile and hPutStr works.